# Adding an extra dimension of size 1 and overhead

Tags: optimization, time, fortran

Veryreverie suggested an answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/73366165/7462275) to merge two programs (a 2D and a 3D ones). The solution is to have only a 3D program and to set the third dimension to 1 for the the 2D case. I did not imagined this solution because I thought that there would be overhead by adding an useful third dimension. (Program is written in Fortran)

Then, I did many tests to compare 2D and 3D with third dimension = 1.

For example :

```
module m
  implicit none
  
  type :: int_3dim_t
    integer :: x
    integer :: y
    integer :: z
  end type int_3dim_t
  
end module m

program main
  use m
  implicit none
  
  type(int_3dim_t) :: ii_curr, full_dim
  real, dimension(:,:,:,:), allocatable :: myMatrix
  real :: aaa
  integer :: ll
  
  open(unit=50,file='dim2.dat',status='old')
  read(50,*) full_dim%x,full_dim%y
  close(50)
  full_dim%z = 1
  allocate(myMatrix(1:8,1:full_dim%x,1:full_dim%y,1:full_dim%z))
    
  associate (ii_x => ii_curr%x, ii_y => ii_curr%y, ii_z => ii_curr%z)
  do ii_z = 1, full_dim%z
    do ii_y = 1, full_dim%y
      do ii_x = 1, full_dim%x
        do ll=1,8
          myMatrix(ll,ii_curr%x,ii_curr%y,ii_curr%z) = myMatrix(ll,ii_curr%x,ii_curr%y,ii_curr%z) + my_calc(ii_curr,ll)
        enddo
      enddo
    enddo
  enddo
  end associate
  
  print *,myMatrix(:,10,10,1)
  
contains

  real function my_calc(ii,ll)
    type(int_3dim_t), intent(in) :: ii
    integer, intent(in) :: ll
    
    my_calc = sqrt(real((ii%x/100.0)**2+(ii%y/100.0)**2))*ll
    
  end function my_calc
    
end program main
```

The input file is `10000 10000` (another values do not change the conclusion), gfortran version is `12.1.1` and `O2` optimisation flag is used.
(For 2D version, everything concerning the third dimension is removed)

And surprisingly, I did not found any difference in execution time.
So, I am looking for simple examples where this third dimension (set to 1) has an effect on the execution time. (Of course, with the correct fortran loop order : first indice in the innner loop and last indice in the outer loop)

Comment: If you keep the loop of length 1 outermost why are you surprised that there is negligible overhead? It's done once per loop nest, which then does 10000x10000 iterations in the case you have above. I guess if you have it innermost you might see something, but that's about the only way I can see there being an issue.

Comment: @Ian Bush. Because It needs three integers instead of two to access to the array value. Of course, with z in the innermost, it takes more time.

Comment: It won't decode the full set of indices each time for regular array accesses, it will just increment a pointer by the appropriate amount. So 1 index or 7 once in the loop it will take the same time.

Comment: @Ian Bush. Thanks for answer. I suppose this is due to compiler optimisation. Is  the current array position kept for all arrays ? I have not knowledge in compiler optimisation process. Do you have any links to advise me ?